# Unable to publish binaries to the file system in SDL Web 8.1

Tags: deployer, web8

I'm using the new Deployer Web Service for SDL Web 8.1 (Installed as a Windows Service) but it seems to be unable to publish any binary files to the file system.

When I publish everything to the Broker Database, publishing is successful. When I set everything to go to the file system, publishing fails. If I remove the images from the components, publishing is successful. In my publishing scenario I require everything to go to the file system.

Error message in the deployer log:

```
2016-06-24 09:42:12,927 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-20600-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed. Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-20600-66560. Unable to store item inside current transaction
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:219) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:107) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:71) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.lambda$pipelineRunnable$1(TransactionManager.java:345) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-20600-66560
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:126) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:106) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:207) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to store item inside current transaction
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:156) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Can't read file c:\tridion\dataweb8\binaryvariant\binaryurl\/Images/opengraph_tcm7-7558.jpg
    at com.tridion.broker.meta.MetaUtils.readURIFromFile(MetaUtils.java:109) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.binaryvariant.FSBinaryVariantDAO.findByMetaFile(FSBinaryVariantDAO.java:435) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.binaryvariant.FSBinaryVariantDAO.findByURL(FSBinaryVariantDAO.java:223) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.binaryvariant.FSBinaryVariantDAO.findByURL(FSBinaryVariantDAO.java:212) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.BinaryCheckerWorker.doDeploy(BinaryCheckerWorker.java:86) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionLogItemWorker.doWork(TransactionLogItemWorker.java:27) ~[cd_model-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:150) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\tridion\dataweb8\binaryvariant\binaryurl\Images\opengraph_tcm7-7558.jpg
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at com.tridion.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:443) ~[cd_common_util-8.1.1-1002.jar:8.1.1-1002]
    at com.tridion.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:417) ~[cd_common_util-8.1.1-1002.jar:8.1.1-1002]
    at com.tridion.broker.meta.MetaUtils.readURIFromFile(MetaUtils.java:101) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Permissions don't seem to be an issue as the page files are writing fine when there isn't an image in the component?

I'm using the out of the box Default Page Template and Default Component Template

Snippet of my storage config file for the deployer:

```
<Storages>
    <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="c:\tridion\dataweb8" />
    </Storage>
</Storages>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
</ItemTypes>
```

Version details:

SDL Web Content Manager - Build 8.1.0

SDL Web Content Manager Explorer - Build 8.1.0.194

Update Version - Cumulative Update 1 for SDL Web 8 (March 2016)

**UPDATE**

It seems that the issue is with the Metadata type mapping as my images have Metadata set against them. Setting this to defaultdb and publishing works:

```
<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultdb"/>
```

Setting this to defaultFile and publishing fails:

```
<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

Unfortunately this is not an option for me as I require everything to go to the filesystem

Answer (score 1):

try to set this into your cd_storage_conf.xml:

```
<Storages>
    <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="c:\tridion\dataweb8" />
    </Storage>
</Storages>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

Good Luck!

2nd Edition:

check your publication properties if you have well configured your path with backslash "\" or normal slash "/"

[image]

Comment: That does get the binaries to publish but in my scenario I want to publish everything to the file system so setting defaultStorageId="defaultdb" isn't an option. I guess this means that it must be one of the other typeMappings that is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the Metadata typeMapping that is the issue. Setting that to defaultdb and the page publishes fine. Setting that to defaultFile and publishing fails

Comment: Regarding your second edition update: The path is fine but in the documentation it says: "This setting is no longer relevant if you use the new publishing framework introduced in SDL Web 8."

Comment: @Ryan - so is it that /Images/ shouldn't be being read from the publication properties but it is? and reversing to Images\ has no effect?

Comment: I've just had a reply from SDL and they have a hotfix for it that I am waiting to be sent and then I will apply it to see if it fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is known defect since we encountered a similar issue with one of our other customers but I'm not sure if a hotfix was released for this.

Please reach out to Customer Support for further information about the hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should  review the Documentation about  Metadata on FileSystem:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-12152D7A-A02C-4073-BE86-B188D108109E
"Metadata stored on the local file system is deprecated as of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 in favor of storage of metadata in the database. Storing metadata in a database requires database licences."